# React Native cannot debug remotely

Tags: react-native

[image]

I'm facing this error while trying to debug remotely react native app made with expo.
Opening http://localhost:19000/debugger-ui/ I got Status: Disconnected from proxy. Attempting reconnection. Is node server running?
I'm using a simulator not a physical device. I've tried also Android simulator and I get a similar error.

React native version I'm using: 0.68.2.
A previous app with version 0.64.3 the debugger worked so I think it might be related with the version.

Thank to who might help.

Comment: I have the same issue, trying to use the React Native Debugger app, but I can't get past trying to enable remote debug JS. Did you find a solution?